# tabular multicolumn mismatch

Tags: tables

I tried to create a table

```
\begin{tabular} {|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{1} &        \multicolumn{2}{|c}{1} &            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1} \\
    \hline
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

the output is

[image]

What is wrong with spotted mismatch of vertical lines? How to align them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `|` after the `c`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|} 
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1} \\ 
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

(but the advice is: *don't use vertical rules at all!*).

[image]

*Edit:* example of table without vertical rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*6{l}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @CarLaTeX. Thank you so much. It works. But I don't understand your last comment. `don't use vertical rules at all!` . What does it mean? Do you means I should not use `\multicolumn`? Then how could I merge cells?

Comment: @user15964 Do use `multicolum` but not the vertical rules in all the table, I'll edit my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: @user15964 See my edit. I've also used `booktabs` package, I  recommend to you to read Section 2 of its [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).